# How to move point to the end of another buffer, using `with-current-buffer` and `goto-char`?

Tags: buffers, scrolling, point, save-excursion, window-point

I'm trying to implement «effective append» for log buffer, e.g. if a `point` is at `point-max` position then insert text and move `point` to new `point-max`, otherwise append text and preserve `point` position.
I though this will be very trivial code:

```el
(with-current-buffer
  (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")
  (if (eq (point) (point-max))
      (insert "\n;; ===\n")
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "\n;; ===\n"))))
```

However, this works as expected only if invoked in `*scratch*` buffer:

- having point somewhere in the middle => text appended, point not moved
- having point at the end of buffer => text appended, point at the end

Now if I change buffer and invoke this command again, point never goes to new point-max and always stays where it was.

Simple tests showed that `if` statement gives correct results always, thus it is correct branch selected. I also tried explicitly move point or do scroll in `true`-branch, but nothing helped:

```el
(if (eq (point) (point-max))
    (progn
      (insert "\n;; ===\n")
      (View-scroll-to-buffer-end)  ;; not works
      (goto-char (point-max)))     ;; so does it too
  (…))
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're probably missing the existence of a "window-point". To test your code, make sure *scratch* is not shown in any window (i.e (get-buffer-window "*scratch*") returns nil), then run your code and go to *scratch* again.

Comment: @YoungFrog well, if `*scratch*` buffer is not visible in any window I have same behaviour: point does not move to the end of buffer even if it should. Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: I can't reproduce, then. Please try https://gist.github.com/YoungFrog/d7db1fb00e30ef93e9d7 and report output.

Comment: @YoungFrog same things: if I eval `M-:` your code with `*scratch*` as current buffer it works as expected. If I have other buffer as current with/without visible scratch buffer point does not moves all the time. There is also `window-point-insertion-type` but I need to learn about it and make some tests.

Comment: I don't understand why you have that problem, but I have proposed an answer anyway because I still think I'm right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code will help. It is modified from an example in the emacs-lisp intro at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/append_002dto_002dbuffer-overview.html.

```el
(defun append-string-to-buffer (buffer string)
  ;; Modified from append-to-buffer, defined in the emacs-lisp intro
  "Append to specified buffer the specified text.
It is inserted into that buffer at end of buffer.

When calling from a program, give two arguments:
BUFFER (or buffer name), and the STRING to be copied."
  (interactive
   (list (read-buffer "Append to buffer: " (other-buffer
                                            (current-buffer) t))
         (read-string "String to append: ")))

  (let* ((append-to (get-buffer-create buffer))
         (windows (get-buffer-window-list append-to t t))
         move-point-in-windows)
    (with-current-buffer append-to
      (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
      ;; record in which windows we should keep point at eob.
      (dolist (window windows)
        (when (= (window-point window) (point-max))
          (push window move-point-in-windows)))
      (let (return-to-position)
        ;; decide whether we should reset point to return-to-position
        ;; or leave it at eob.
        (unless (= (point) (point-max))
          (setq return-to-position (point))
          (goto-char (point-max)))
        (insert string)
        (when return-to-position
          (goto-char return-to-position)))
      ;; advance to point-max in windows where it is needed
      (dolist (window move-point-in-windows)
        (set-window-point window (point-max))))))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works even better than expected! For example, if I have two windows with target buffer viewed it behaves correctly and independently for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```el
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "MY-BUF")
  (let ((orig (point)))
    (if (eq (point) (point-max))
    (insert "\n;; ===\n")
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "\n;; ===\n")
      (goto-char orig))))
```

BTW I'd not use `save-excursion` inside `with-current-buffer`, as `save-excursion` is a complex funciton, while `goto-char orig` looks cleaner.

Comment: Let me check. Did you missed `progn` for else-branch, didn't you? Also save excursion preserves active region if it present.

Comment: Andreas Röhler, your code behaves exact as mine, did you tested it? Also looks like I do not need `progn` for else part.

Comment: @Geradlus_RU Else-part is implicit: if a point is at point-max position then insert text and move point to new point-max - the second half of this sentence is redundant, as insertion will and at point-max. And yes, your code should work already.